# Image as a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone send a code how to make image as a sidebar,i want the whole image with width exp. 40%,but height to take a size of whole page without margins.I tried something but have no idea how to do it.(nothing i do works)

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_bw_portfolio.htm

Something like this in w3,i looked at the source code but i did not understand it very well.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Unfortunately this site isn't a free code service and it's expected to show some efforts of an existing problem with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of where your troubles are. Maybe give a browse around [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for details on how to construct a better question then come on back when you've got a more concise problem to solve. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

USE CSS property

```
background-image:url('your image path/imagename.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
min-height:100%;
```

and other property such as "width" to control the width of image.

Comment: Tnx man but i saw that and thats the problem,it doesnt want to show me the image when i use the same code from w3 school(including the code with the comment <!-- Sidebar with image -->)

Comment: it is because you have to define the height.

Comment: It still doesnt work,idk why but shouldnt be working bcs im using the same code

Comment: Nvm mind i just realised its bcs they had some additional code in head section.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> This one.And thats why i wasnt able to just use their style code bcs they had this one too.Tnx again tho.

Answer (score 0):

In the div of your side bar you could put

```css
.main {width: 1200px;}
.sidebar {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif") repeat-y scroll left top transparent;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 800px;
  float: left;
}
.content{
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```